# Get string from fragment to non-activity class then convert to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am trying to pass a I from a fragment to a non-activity class and convert the string to a JSONObject.

In my fragment I stored the string I need in a share preference

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list, container, false);

    //super.onCreate();
    VolleyGet.getInstance(getActivity());
    VolleyGet.getInstance().VolleyGET(domain, api, new CustomListener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void getResult(String result){
            if (!result.isEmpty())
            {
                Log.e("storelist---------->", result);

                SharedPreferences sp1=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("storeList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
                editor.putString("storeList", result);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

In my non-activity class I tried getting the shared preference like this:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>{


Context context;
JSONArray storeArray;



SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("storeList", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String storeList = preferences.getString("storeList", "");


System.out.println("storelist", storeList);
storeArray = new JSONArray(storeList);
JSONObject jObj = storeArray.getJSONObject(0);
List<Movie>     mItems;

    public CardAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("this will come from the JSONObject");
        movie.setThumbnail(R.drawable.will come from JSONObject);
        mItems.add(movie);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.store_cardview, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Movie movie = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvMovie.setText(movie.getName());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(movie.getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvMovie;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvMovie = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie);
        }
    }
```

}

I am getting error on 1.cannot resolve symbol println 2.Unknown class:storelist 3.storearray is also unknown

please help, thank you!

Comment: You can't just println outside of a method

Comment: Do you really need the shared preferences in the adapter? Why can't you extract the json array / object before creating the adapter?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can extract it outside but still I would like to know how to get the shared preferences in the class, thank you!

Comment: 1) Please show the constructor for the class. Currently, your `context` value is null, so this code should not run (if it did compile). 2) I don't know what error you are referencing by `Unknown class:storelist`, because you declare `storeList` just fine

Comment: @cricket_007 1) I have edited the class 2) Me to, i can't figure out why my storeList doesn't work

Comment: Is this your actual code? What does `movie.setThumbnail(R.drawable.will come from JSONObject);` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot `System.out.println` or access the un-initialized Context where you have done it (outside the scope of your issue).

Regarding the other errors, I don't think you've shown the correct code, but if the error says "storelist", then your variable is actually `storeList`, so that looks like a typo.

Look at any tutorial for the RecyclerView adapter, the Constructor often is provided the Context. That is what you need to access the SharedPreferences.

```
public class CardAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private JSONArray mArray;
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    public CardAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("storeList", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mArray = new JSONArray(mPrefs.getString("storeList", "[]"));
    }

}
```

Comment: In regards of your comment _You can't just println outside of a method_ not outside of a block to be precise ;)